# CSS hover transition - how to remove delay?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I can't believe I am having trouble with a basic transition... but alas, I am. I can't actually find another post with this problem, so there must be something specifically wrong with my code.

I am doing a simple transition with max-height so that when you hover over a menu item, the sub-menu slides down, like so:

```
ul.sidenav ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    max-height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:max-height 1s ease-in-out;
    }

ul.sidenav > li:hover > ul {max-height:999px;}
```

This works fine on mouseover, but on mouse-out there is a noticeable delay before it slides back up. I've tried various ease-in/ease-out settings, and I've tried adding a separate time to the mouse-out. But that delay remains.

What is going on? Here is a fiddle showing the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/t5Wv2/8/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is you have `ul.sidenav > li:hover > ul` set to `max-height: 999px`

When you mouseout, it is taking 1 second to transition the `max-height` from `999px` to `0px`—you're just not seeing it happen.

Change the `max-height` to something closer to the actual height (i.e. `99px`) and lower the `transition-duration` to `0.25s` and you'll see a difference.

```
ul.sidenav ul {
  transition:max-height 0.25s ease-in-out;
}

ul.sidenav > li:hover > ul {max-height:99px;}
```

Keep in mind if you add more sub-menu items and the height exceeds `99px`, the overflow will be hidden, so you'll have to increase the `max-height` to show the hidden items.

Comment: Oh man! Of course. That completely makes sense and I didn't even think about how it would have to essentially "count down" from 999 to 0. Thank you. That solved it.

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, it isn't smart enough to know the actual height of the elements inside, so it only knows to transition from the max-height you have set.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Netron/t5Wv2/22/)

Fix delay solution:

Put cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1) transition function for element.

```
.text {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0, 1);
  &.full {
    max-height: 1000px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```